# setInterval triggers function multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, onready

EDIT: what i mean by fires multiple times, is that newjob() will fire 3 times, every 5 seconds...so in 20 seconds i'll have it 12 times triggered, instead of the 4 times that i would want. so it's triggeres multiple times every 5 seconds, instead of once every 5 seconds.

I have a function that i created using Toastr to display a message on my web application. i'm eventually going to tie it to an ajax request to an API to determine whether or not to display a message, but for now i'm just testing how it looks.

i am setting an interval, but it fires the function inside of it multiple times (usually 3).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function () {
        newJob();
    }, 5000);
});
```

i can't do setInterval( function(e) { } as e is undefined, as there is no event associated with it, on click, i've used e.stopImmediatePropagation(); to have it only fire once.
how can i stop this immediate propagation on set interval if i don't have e?

thank you.

EDIT: full code:

```
var newJob = function(e) {
    var i = -1;
    var $toastlast;

    var getMessage = function () {
        var msgs = ["There's a new job in the job dispatch queue", "A job pending approval has timed out"];
        i++;
        if (i === msgs.length) {
            i = 0;
        }

        return msgs[i];
    };

    var shortCutFunction = "success"; // 'success' or 'error'

    toastr.options = {
        closeButton: true,
        progressBar: true,
        debug: false,
        positionClass: 'toast-top-full-width',
        onclick: null,
        timeOut: "0",
        extendedTimeOut: "0",
        showDuration: "0",
        hideDuration: "0",
        showEasing: "swing",
        hideEasing: "linear",
        showMethod: "fadeIn",
        hideMethod: "fadeOut",
    };


    toastr.options.onclick = function () {
        window.location.href = "/dispatcher";
    };

    var msg = getMessage();

    $("#toastrOptions").text("Command: toastr["
                    + shortCutFunction
                    + "](\""
                    + msg
                    + "\")\n\ntoastr.options = "
                    + JSON.stringify(toastr.options, null, 2)
    );

    var $toast = toastr[shortCutFunction](msg);

};

$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function () {
        console.log('set interval');
        newJob();
    }, 5000);


});
```

and this is my index.phtml file:

```
    <?php
echo $this->headScript()->appendFile($this->basePath() . '/plugins/toastr/toastr.js')
echo $this->headScript()->appendFile($this->basePath().'/js/dispatchernotification.js');
    ?>
```

all i'm doing is adding the javascript of what i want running to my index.phtml file and the toastr library.
by console.loging inside interval, i get three logs.

here's a fiddle..not sure how to run it though as it's on ready
http://jsfiddle.net/efecarranza/rfvbhr1o/

Comment: Whats your aim? setInterval is meant to fire multiple times.

Comment: Based on your code, `setInterval` fires every 5 seconds.  Is that not what you want?  If you only want it to fire once, use `setTimeout` instead.

Comment: sorry, i meant to say that newJob() fires multiple times, every 5 seconds...so every 5 seconds, i'll get 3 instances of newjob

Comment: Can you recreate the issue in a fiddle?

Comment: Add the code of your `NewJob()` function to your question

Comment: `i've used e.stopImmediatePropagation(); to have it only fire once` This has nothing to do with your posted code. So if you bind some event inside `newJob()`, at least post it

Answer (score 5):

Make sure to put your `setInterval` outside of `$(document).ready(function() {...})`. So it will be like:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    ... some code ...
});

var myInterval;
clearInterval(myInterval);
myInterval = setInterval(function() {
    ... your code is here ...
}, 5000);

</script>
```

For some reason, if it's within `$(document).ready()` every time you dynamically bring the same page again it double-sets the `setInterval` in progression and `clearInterval` function doesn't help until you actually refresh the browser.

Answer (score 4):

[`setInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) will continue endlessly. I think you're looking for [`setTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).

Comment: sorry, i meant to say that newJob() fires multiple times, every 5 seconds...so every 5 seconds, i'll get 3 instances of newjob

Answer (score 2):

`setInterval`: call a function repeatedly every x milliseconds
`setTimeOut`: call a function after x milliseconds.

You have two options:

Clear the interval when it isn't necessary anymore:

```
var intervalId;
$(document).ready(function() {
    intervalId = setInterval(function () {
        newJob();
    }, 5000);
});

// At some other point
clearInterval(intervalId);
```

Or, the simpler solution in your case, use setTimeout:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            newJob();
        }, 5000);
    });
```

Comment: i miscommunicated what was going on: my newJob fires multiple times, per 'turn' or 'loop' of setinterval, so it'll trigger many times per 5 seconds, instead of once every 5 seconds

Comment: Do you have this code repeated somewhere? What does you newjob-function look like?

Comment: there i added the full code and a fiddle, not sure how to run though as it's on ready.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you can add a jsfiddle with your code so we can see what's going wrong exactly. It's possible that for whatever reason the setInterval function is being called multiple times. Try adding a console.log statement at the start of that function to check if that's the case.

If it is and you can't figure out why (and neither can we without knowing your code), you could place a check at the start of the function like this:

```
if (typeof this.installInterval.done == "undefined") {
  /*a bunch of code*/
  this.installInterval.done = true
}
```

Comment: What is the intended behavior exactly? The way your code is set up, the only message that will ever be shown is "There's a new job in the job dispatch queue". You reset i to -1 every time you call newJob, which is once every 5000ms.

Also, make sure that you select jquery in the frameworks on the left in your jsfiddle, otherwise your code doesn't work.

Comment: it works fine on fiddle, thank you for the jquery clarification. might be a zend framework thing or something that displays it twice, i have to check that then i suppose. 
i'm extending it to trigger via ajax post request later on, ajax will trigger every so many seconds, check something against an API, and then on thre reponse success or failure will show a different message.

Answer (score 0):

May be by mistake you are calling your script twice as I did!
In the code below I have called 'testLoop.js' two times.

```
<script src="../js/testLoop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/testLoop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/cube.js"></script>
```